# How to configure the toolbar in CKEditor?

Tags: wysiwyg, toolbar

I've installed CKEditor in my drupal instance and all seems to work well until I realized, I can't change the text size (missing drop down). I went to `admin/config/content/ckeditor` and selected and saved `Toolbar` `full` from the examples, which feature a `Size` dropdown as shows in the "current toolbar' preview. I did this for both existing profiles, `Advanced` and `Full`. However, if I then go to `admin/structure/block/add` to add a new block, `CKEditor` still does not show a size drop down so that I could change the text size. Why not, what am I missing?

**EDIT 1**

I went to http://ckeditor.com/download and downloaded the **full package** which I then just copied to my existing `sites/all/modules/ckeditor/ckeditor` overwriting the existing **standard package** copy. I've reset the cache`, however what I'm seeing now is this:

[image: CKEditor toolbar]

The *Size* drop-down is visible but other buttons have failed to load their icons.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you flush the cache?

Comment: @NoSssweat Yes I have, see **EDIT 1** above

Comment: You have the latest version of the drupal module, 7.x-1.16 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible you are using a version of CKEditor (the editor, not the drupal module) that doesn't have the font size and family plugin.

See the different versions at http://ckeditor.com/download (click the "Compare packages" link to see what is included in each package).

On that page you can see that only the full version has the "Font Size and Family (font)" package, so if you are using one of the other version then it won't have that package.

It is also possible to use the "Or let me customize CKEditor" option to create a custom version of CKEditor that contains just the plugins you require.
If using that make sure you include the "Font Size and Family (font)" package.

There is an [issue here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1960000) on Drupal.org regarding messages to the admin to notify them of missing plugins.

Comment: please see **EDIT 1** above

Answer (score 1):

I "fixed" it by completely reinstalling CKEditor as described on http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_for_Drupal/Open_Source/Drupal_7/Installation that worked just fine!